# SSRS Repeat Header per row on part of a page?

Tags: reporting-services

I am using SQL Server Report Service and wanted to know if there is a way to display headers one per row on part of page while using the standard header in a group for the rest.

I have results from a surey that I need to display and most of the survey is Strongly Agree, Agree, Neutral, Disagree, Strongly Disagree.  But the first two rows involves time periods like 7a-10a, 10a-1p, 1p-4p, 4p-7p, Saturday and locations and these need to have headers to show what they are.

I am now using two table to do this with the data for time and location on one to split headers per row and survey results on the other to split headers by group.  The data from the SQL Server 2008 does have a Survey_Order column to seperate the two sets.

I can not find a way to get all of it on one table and if anyone has a suggestions how to display all of the data using one table on the SSRS?

Comment: If you provide some more field names and what sort of row you want to have the header repeated on, we can provide better answers. (A sketch of what you are trying to accomplish would be really helpful.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of displaying true "headers" for the header row you want repeated one per data row, you can add a second data row. Style it to look like headers. Then set the Row Visibility to only show the row when the question needs this second header row.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I set up one row for a header row in the group and one outside of the group.  I then placed a IIF() statement in each header row Visibility to determine which row to display when I needed it.  It worked perfectly.